# In Yakuza Dead Souls, should I sell the figures to Kamiyama?

Tags: yakuza-dead-souls

I've just run across Kamiyama and he's told me he'll pay 50k for Cutie Girl Figure and 150k for SR Love Shine Figure.

Should I sell to him, or hold onto these for later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, he's into that kinda stuff. I believe he's the only NPC in the game that'll buy/take them.

Comment: Actually, during a certain part of Majima's story one vendor will take them (albeit as proxy).